# Ещё не + краткое прилагательное

Tags: орфография, частица-не

> Однако тем и интересны ранние церкви, что иконография непривычна,
>   **способ изображения** *(кого-чего?)* – **ещё не устойчив**. Чаще всего
>   композиции следуют особой, оригинальной истории, оттого каждый
>   памятник раннего периода отличается своеобразием и неповторимостью.

Слитно, раздельно или по желанию пишущего?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если возможно двоякое толкование текста - отрицается устойчивость (раздельное написание) или утверждается неустойчивость, подверженность колебаниям (слитное написание), то решает автор, что он хотел сказать.

Мне ближе слитное написание: ещё неустойчив = ещё колеблется, меняется. Может, потому что устойчивость чаще употребляется в прямом значении, а неустойчивость  в переносном тоже достаточно распространено.